# PostgreSQL failed to migrate with error message 'Could not find driver'

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, pdo, xampp

I am currently using Laravel PHP with PostgreSQL as database but while I am migrating my database, I come up with an error **'could not find driver'**. I already removed the `';'` from the `extension=pdo_pgsql`, and `extension=pgsql` of the `php.ini file` then restarted the Apache server but it still does not work. I am using **PostgreSQL v10.5** and **XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2** with **Windows 10** as my Operating System.

I already set up my env. file, the default connection to pgsql. I can't think/search any more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reinstalling PostgreSQL? I also found this article that might be helpful: https://medium.com/@Riverside/how-to-install-apache-php-postgresql-lapp-on-ubuntu-16-04-adb00042c45d

Comment: Not without Ubuntu bash, check out this article on installing it for Windows 10: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: I tried reinstalling my PostgreSQL 10.5 via the installer but it still didn't work.